During Navigation This Error is showing ("There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree") What would be the reason?
                               Home Screen

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/Widget/Navigation.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/Widget/Shoetile.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/model/Shoemodel.dart';

class Homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Homescreen({super.key});

  final searchController = TextEditingController();

  final List<Shoemodel> shoelist = [
    Shoemodel(
        description:
            "The Nike Dunk Low is an easy score for your closet. This mid-80s hoops icon returns with super-durable construction and original colors. With ankle padding and rubber traction, this one is a slam dunk.",
        imagepath: "assets/images/Shoe1.png",
        name: "Nike Dunk Low",
        pricing: "\$90"),
    Shoemodel(
        description:
            "The Nike Dunk Low is an easy score for your closet. This mid-80s hoops icon returns with super-durable construction and original colors. With ankle padding and rubber traction, this one is a slam dunk.",
        imagepath: "assets/images/shoe2.png",
        name: "Nike Air Max 90",
        pricing: "\$89.97"),
    Shoemodel(
        description:
            "The Nike Dunk Low is an easy score for your closet. This mid-80s hoops icon returns with super-durable construction and original colors. With ankle padding and rubber traction, this one is a slam dunk.",
        imagepath: "assets/images/shoe3.png",
        name: "Nike Air Max 90",
        pricing: "\$89.97"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: searchController,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  label: const Text("Search Here"),
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        searchController.clear();
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.clear)),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18))),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Everyone Flies... Some Fly Longer Than Others",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Hot Picks",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "see all",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: shoelist.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Shoetile(shoemodel: shoelist[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const Navigation(),
    );
  }
}
                            Shoetile Screen

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/Screen/Detailscreen.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/model/Shoemodel.dart';

class Shoetile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Shoetile({super.key, required this.shoemodel});

  final Shoemodel shoemodel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Detailscreen(model: shoemodel),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Hero(
                tag: shoemodel.name, // Unique tag
                child: Image.asset(
                  shoemodel.imagepath,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                shoemodel.name,
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: Text(
                  shoemodel.description,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      shoemodel.pricing,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 70,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

                                  

```                       Detail Screen

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/model/Shoemodel.dart';
class Detailscreen extends StatelessWidget {
const Detailscreen({super.key, required this.model});
final Shoemodel model;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: Column(
children: [
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
child: IconButton(
style: IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
onPressed: () {
Navigator.pop(context);
},
icon: const Icon(
Icons.arrow_back,
color: Colors.white,
),
),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
child: Text(
model.name,
style: const TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
child: IconButton(
style: IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
onPressed: () {
Navigator.pop(context);
},
icon: const Icon(
Icons.search,
color: Colors.white,
),
),
),
],
),
SizedBox(
width: 500,
height: 300,
child: Hero(
tag: model.name, // Unique tag
child: Image.asset(model.imagepath),
),
),
const SizedBox(
height: 20,
),
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
),
),
],
),
);
}
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shoes_app/model/Shoemodel.dart';

class Detailscreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detailscreen({super.key, required this.model});

  final Shoemodel model;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                child: IconButton(
                  style: IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                child: Text(
                  model.name,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                child: IconButton(
                  style: IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            child: Hero(
              tag: model.name, // Unique tag
              child: Image.asset(model.imagepath),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

